# Installing Ubuntu on top of Mac and Windows 7

Tags: macos, partitioning, macbook, macbook-pro, boot-partition

I have a macbook pro8,1. I could dual boot OSX and windows 7 using bootcamp.
Now, I want to triple boot; that is, I want to have Ubuntu too. However, when I run the Ubuntu installer and get to the partition page, I couldn't see any partitions that I could see from using either the disk utility on Mac or the windows' Disk Management tool on Windows 7. I suspect that this is happening because the partition scheme that the disk is using right now is MBR. Therefore, if I can somehow manage to change the partition scheme back to GUID, I maybe able to intall Ubuntu by following a triple boot tutorial (http://lifehacker.com/5531037/how-to-triple-boot-your-mac-with-windows-and-linux-no-boot-camp-required)

To turn my partition scheme back to GUID, I am planning to erase all paritions on disk and then repartitions again.

Do you have any other suggestions?

[image: My disk info]

[Disk Utility](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rz10.png)

Comment: Next time please don't ask multiple unrelated questions in a single post.

Comment: I'd forget question 1. Rewrite your post to concentrate on question 2… which is your actual issue. TBH, the only thing I know of that could possibly recover that to GUID is [iPartition](https://coriolis-systems.com/iPartition/) though whether it would leave the bootcamp or ubuntu partitions bootable is  questionable, but it might get your Mac partition back to a bootable state. I'd definitely backup whatever you can currently read from it before attempting anything further. Don't let any utility turn it into Core Storage, or iPartition will no longer work.

Comment: I think it was too late for a rewrite, @Tetsujin & Weidong, given that there was already an answer. [Chameleon question...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) :-(

Answer (score 1):

The boot picker is in the boot ROM, not on any disk.  No Apple partitioning tool would turn your disk from GPT to MBR, but they *would* put a Protective MBR on the disk so MBR-based tools will realize the disk is partitioned and not mess with it.

Comment: What method would you suggest to remove MBR, so I can resize my paritition using disk utility. The buttons on the partition section of the Disk Utility is grayed out. I can only resize some partitions using disk genius. I can't even upgrade my osx because the installer doesn't allow the os to be installed on a disk that uses the MBR partition scheme. What I am thinking is to back up my data, erase the entire disk, and then repartition again. If I do this, osx will be lost. Can I simply go to the recovery mode, COMMAND + R, and reinstall the os from there?

Comment: post the results of `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list` to your question

Comment: a screenshot of my running diskutil list and diskutil cs list:http://i.stack.imgur.com/QfvBl.png

Answer (score 0):

### STOP!!!

***It appears that your disk may be badly damaged!***

Your `diskutil list` output claims that the disk is in "FDisk" (MBR) format; however, the first partition listed is of type 0xEE. This type code is reserved as a placeholder for GPT disks, and a partition of this type should be present *only* on GPT disks. `diskutil` hasn't provided the exact start and end points of that partition, which are important for figuring out what's going on. (A GPT disks' type-0xEE MBR placeholder will normally start on sector 1.)

Your disk has additional MBR partitions. Ordinarily, the presence of a type-0xEE partition along with other MBR partitions indicates that the disk has a [hybrid MBR,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) which is an ugly and dangerous hack that Apple uses to enable Windows to boot in BIOS mode on its normally GPT-using and EFI-booting Macs. When so set up, OS X views the disk as being a GPT disk, but Windows treats it as an MBR disk. A hybrid MBR permits replicating up to three GPT partitions on the MBR side, which is normally enough to get Windows working.

The really scary part of your configuration is that it includes MBR partitions numbered 5 and 6. These numbers are used by logical partitions, which in turn means that you must be using an extended partition (not shown by `diskutil`). This is an *extremely* dangerous configuration for a hybrid MBR, for reasons described on my hybrid MBR page to which I've linked (the second bullet point under "Dangers and Problems of a Hybrid MBR").

What I suspect happened is that you set up a hybrid MBR (perhaps not understanding the details) as part of your initial dual-boot configuration. You then used Windows tools (or perhaps Linux's `fdisk` or some other GPT-unaware tool) to create new partitions for Linux; but since Windows treats the disk as an MBR disk and doesn't know anything about GPT (which, importantly, is the *real* partition table; the MBR just contains copies of *some* GPT partitions), you created logical partitions. These partitions may overlap some other GPT partition(s), so you could have two *incompatible* partition tables on your disk.

If I'm right about this, you must identify *both* the GPT and MBR partitions on the disk, with sector-level precision. I'm not sure of the OS X or Windows tools you'd use for this task. In Linux, you'd use `fdisk` to list the MBR partitions and `gdisk` to list the GPT partitions. You should then compare the two. With any luck, some of them will be identical. (Ignore the 0xEE partition on the MBR side.) If a partition exists on the GPT side but the MBR side has no partitions in that space, you can use that particular GPT partition. Likewise if there's an MBR partition where no GPT partition exists. If, though, a part of the disk has different GPT and MBR partitions, you may have already suffered data loss. You can try recovering data using one partition definition or another, but that will be tricky.

Once you've got a list of all your partitions, and have recovered data as best as you can, you can use `gdisk` to create a consistent GPT data set. I recommend shutting down and rebooting at this point. You can then use `gdisk` to create a fresh hybrid MBR, which unfortunately you pretty much require to dual-boot with Windows 7.

To move on to installing Linux, you should use a GPT-aware tool to repartition the disk. This may wipe out your hybrid MBR, so you may need to re-create it after you've installed Ubuntu.

All that said, I may be wrong. It's possible that you've converted your disk from GPT to MBR form, but you've set the 0xEE type code inappropriately on an otherwise-legitimate MBR partition. If so, I apologize for the panic, but you really must figure out what that partition is and what its type code should be, so as to avoid problems with some utility becoming confused and possibly doing something very very bad. (Ubuntu's installer seeing the disk as empty is a relatively benign symptom compared to what might happen.)